# Why is the building system not available/not installed?

Tags: python

OK, so basically, after I downloaded Sublime Text and Python 3 (I cannot deselect the "Install launcher for all users" thing) according to *Crash Course Python*, I followed the instructions of how to change the build system, by entering `"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"]`, then saved this file under the name "Python3.sublime-build." When I have changed the building system under Tools to Python3. When I finished, I entered the code `print("Hello Python World!")`, but in the console where we would usually see the things pop up, I only got "Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640[Finished](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640%5BFinished) in 0.2s]"

Why is this?

Comment: Is `python3` actually on your Path, or should it be `python3.exe`?

Comment: python3 is on my PATH, but i also ticked the "install launcher for all users."

Comment: But I downloaded python 3.8 instead of 3.7 because when i go to python.org, i can only see the download link for python 3.8.5

Comment: When you open a command line, does it find / can you execute `python3`? Or `python.exe`? How exactly is Python on your path? The parent-directory, or the one actually containing the executable? Have you tried putting the whole path to the executable into the Sublime command?